# How to calculate percentage row in SSRS Tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, count

I am using SSRS 2008 and trying to calculate the following percentage in my tablix:

```
sum(Fields!Last14Days_Ct.Value) / countdistinct(Fields!Client.Value)
```

So Last14Days_Ct can be = 1 or 0.  I want to sum all of these integer values.  Client field is a VARCHAR, and there can be multiple rows / Client.  So what I want to do is to calculate the % of Clients within the last 14 days.  In other words, each Client has one field "Last14Days_Ct" = 1 or 0.  So I just want to calculate the percentage of clients that happened in last 14 days.  Here is the SSRS formula I tried right now:

```
=iif(countdistinct(Fields!Client.Value)=0,0,sum(Fields!Last14Days_Ct.Value)
/iif(countdistinct(Fields!Client.Value)=0,1,countdistinct(Fields!Client.Value)))
```

And I grouped that row on Fields!Last14Days_Ct.Value.

But problem is that now when I view it in ReportViewer, it shows 2 rows: when Last14Days_Ct = 1 and 0.  I only want the row where it = 1 to appear.  But if I apply a filter to that group on = 1, it always shows 100%.  How can I properly calculate this value please?

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the filter off, is the calculation displaying correctly? If so, then open group properties for Last14Days_Ct, go to Visibility, and for "When the report is initially run" select "Show or hide based on an expression." Use the expression:

```
=Fields!Last14Days_Ct.Value = 0
```

That way, you only view the 1 values, but all the values are still in scope for your report, so the math in your calculation still works.